# How to mirror directory structure and files with zero size?

Tags: bash, find, directory-structure, macos, touch

I am trying to mirror the directory *and* file structure of a particular directory. However, I want the mirrored files to have no size. So for example, if I had the following directory tree:

```
original_folder
├── images
│   ├── image1.jpg         (2 MB)
│   ├── image2.jpg         (3 MB)
├── videos
│   ├── video1.mp4         (300 MB)
│   ├── video2.mp4         (400 MB)
```

I want the following output:

```
mirrored_folder
├── images
│   ├── image1.jpg         (0 b)
│   ├── image2.jpg         (0 b)
├── videos
│   ├── video1.mp4         (0 b)
│   ├── video2.mp4         (0 b)
```

I tried using the following command in `original_folder`:

```
cd original_folder
find . -name '*' -exec touch ../mirrored_folder/'{}' \;
```

However, this command tries to execute `touch ../mirrored_folder/./images/image1.jpg`. Note the dot which messes the command up. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: that dot won't affect anything, but this command won't create directories by default, so if the destination was empty at the start it'll create a _file_ called images, and then fail when attempting to treat that as a directory

Comment: Why do you think it's the dot that would mess that command up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GNU `cp` (from [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)) can do this:

```
cp -r --attributes-only original_folder/* mirrored_folder/
```

---

From [man cp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html):

> **`--attributes-only`**
>
>   don't copy the file data, just the attributes
>
> **`-R`**, **`-r`**, **`--recursive`**
>
>   copy directories recursively

---

Using `find` command as OP says xe is on MacOS and `cp` command has no `--attributes-only` option:

```
find original_folder/ -type d -exec \
    sh -c 'mkdir -p mirrored_folder/${1#*/}' _ {} \; \
-o -type f -exec \
    sh -c 'touch mirrored_folder/${1#*/}' _ {} \;
```

Note that `find` solution creates fresh directories and files unlike the `cp` solution that was keeping their attributes (default: mode, ownership, timestamps).

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I want! Now the I'm trying to get it with running it on macOS since that flag doesn't seem to exist...

Comment: Thank you for your edit! I just found out how to do it on Mac, which I will add for posterity. 1. Run `brew install coreutils`. 2. If you're using I think `oh-my-zsh`, run `unalias gcp`. 3. Use `gcp` instead of `cp`

Comment: cp should be used with dot after the original dir instead of asterisk (^) in order to copy hidden dot files eg `cp -r --attributes-only original_folder/. mirrored_folder/` which will make 1:1 structure copy - without data.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
cd dest || exit
(cd orig && find . -type d -print0) | xargs -r0 mkdir -p
(cd orig && find . -type f -print0) | xargs -r0 touch
```